# How do I solve "Hash Sum Mismatch" on "apt-get install docker-ce"?

Tags: docker, ubuntu-18.04, docker-ce

I hope you're all well!

This is my first question ever on stack overflow, so if i'm missing anything, just tell me and it'll be my pleasure to update my question.

So, to summarize my problem, I am trying to install Docker-ce on an Ubuntu 18.04 VM by following the official steps at [Docker-Engine Installation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/) and I am getting the error "Hash Sum Mismatch" when running the command "sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io".

I went through the official steps a few times and I've tried the following things so far :

1) The following commands, followed by the official installation steps

```
apt-get clean
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
apt-get clean
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

2) Creation of a file with the following lines, placed at "/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99fixbadproxy", followed by the official installation steps

```
Acquire::http::Pipeline-Depth 0;
Acquire::http::No-Cache true;
Acquire::BrokenProxy    true;
```

3) Installation of other versions of docker-ce with the following commands

```
sudo apt-get install docker-ce 5:19.03.8~3-0~ubuntu-bionic
sudo apt-get install docker-ce 5:19.03.6~3-0~ubuntu-bionic
sudo apt-get install docker-ce 5:18.09.9~3-0~ubuntu-bionic
```

4) I tried installing different repositories (i think they're called repositories) by adding "nightly" or "test" or both after the word "stable" of the following command

```
sudo add-apt-repository \
"deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
$(lsb_release -cs) \
stable"
```

And I think that is pretty much it. I did tried other things but unfortunately i don't remember them because I've been working on this issue for quite some time now.

I did not try on a fresh new installation of Ubuntu 18.04 though.

If I'm missing anything in my question, please let me know!

Take care everybody!

Comment: same problem here, did you find the solution?

Comment: unfortunately, i didn't find any solution. I tried on a fresh install and it works fine, but i cannot really reinstall on the machine i have the problem with.

Comment: i had to use unofficial mirrors, and it worked, next time just google docker ubuntu alternative mirrors

Answer (score 8, accepted):

EXPLANATION and Solution: Quick Fix

This issue is caused by the Windows Hypervisor Platform. This issue cannot be resolved for now (asfar as I know).

A partial fix is at hand though. And I say"partial" because it involves disabling the platform (also known as"Hyper-V") which will probably break other virtualization solutions you have installed since this is enabled manually. Anyway, here's how to disable it and get your VM running again,

1. Shut down the Virtual Machine.
2. Press Windows logo key + X, then hit A to run Command Prompt(powershell) as administrator.
3. Type
   bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
4. When you see"The operation completed succesfully", reboot your windows. After reboot, boot your VM and update/upgrade.

Comment: this worked for me and quite frankly i am amazed! how does that particular setting on the windows host influence what happens on the ubuntu guest?? its black magic

Comment: This is a bug in VirtualBox 6.1 that is resolved in 6.1.16. References: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/19695 and https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/WSL/issues/798

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still having issues with this, I managed to get it working by disabling HyperV (as most people have already suggested). However, on my setup, disabling HyperV using the mentioned approaches didnt actually disable HyperV since my windows machine used HyperV for both CredentialGuard and Secure Boot, both of which needed to be disabled before HyperV was actually fully disabled

If running `systeminfo.exe` in an elevated terminal shows `A hypervisor has been detected. Features required for Hyper-V will not be displayed`, then HyperV is not fully disabled. Disabling credential guard and secure boot coupled with a few restarts (after running all the commands to disable HyperV that have already been mentioned) solved all issues for me.

Just for reference, if HyperV is fully disabled, you should see

```
Hyper-V Requirements:      VM Monitor Mode Extensions: Yes
                           Virtualization Enabled In Firmware: Yes
                           Second Level Address Translation: Yes
                           Data Execution Prevention Available: Yes
```

when running `systeminfo.exe`